# The type name 'value' does not exist in the type 'Memory'

Tags: c#, variables

I want display a memory on a label, i have two classes,
My variable in Class1.cs but i cant read it from Form1.cs

I add 'public' on my variable at Class1.cs
it solve some problems but i cant read this variable from Form1.cs

**Form1 Class:**

```
namespace hilemi
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            label1.Text = (Memory.value)ToString;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Class1:**

```
namespace hilemi
{
    class Memory
    {
        static string progress = "hl2";
        static int adress = 0x545D210;
        public static int value;

        public void main()
        {   
            VAMemory vam = new VAMemory(progress);
            value = vam.ReadInt32((IntPtr)adress);
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error, i cant run my program
The type name 'value' does not exist in the type 'Memory'

Comment: This is not C. Please take care when selecting tags. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then edit your question to improve it, like fixing the language tag and adding the *full* and *complete* error output as text, and add a comment on the line in the shown code where you get it.

Comment: im sorry my first question, i change it, thx.

Comment: Did you meant to type `label1.Text = Memory.value.ToString();`?

Comment: oh i changed it and fixed ty

Comment: There are so many coding flaws in this code... I would like to be honest and help you out by recommending you to first take the basic C# lessons before coding user interface.

Comment: I am not sure that 'value' should be static, especially when you set it in an (instance) constructor

Answer (score 0):

First: Memory.value is not a Type,you have to edit code like below :

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    label1.Text = Memory.value.ToString();
}
```

I recommand you to read [C# Type Casting](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_type_casting.asp)

Second: duplicate namespace,system only need one.

```
namespace hilemi
namespace hilemi
```